# Execute PL/SQL script in C++ using OCCI oracle

Tags: c++, oracle, plsql, sql-scripts, occi

I want to run SQL script from a C++ program. my code goes like this:

```
int main()
{ 
//.....
sql_stmt = "Insert into t1 values ('qwerty');\nInsert into t1 values ('dothar');"
           "//and many more INSERT statements";

sql_stmt = "DECLARE\nrollback_check_counter number;\n"
"BEGIN\n"
"rollback_check_counter :=1;\n"
"SAVEPOINT sp_1;\nIF rollback_check_counter = 1 THEN\n"
"BEGIN\n"+sql_stmt+"EXCEPTION\n"
"WHEN PROGRAM_ERROR THEN\n"
"rollback_check_counter :=0;\n"
"ROLLBACK TO sp_1;\n"
"WHEN OTHERS THEN\n"
"rollback_check_counter :=0;\n"
"ROLLBACK TO sp_1;\n"
"END;\n"
"END IF;\n"
"commit;\n"
"END;";


try 
{
    Connection *conn = env->createConnection(user,passwd); //error prone
    Statement *stmt = conn->createStatement();
    stmt->setSQL(sql_stmt);
    row_count = stmt->execute(); //stmt->execute(sql_stmt);

    Connection::conn->terminateStatement(Statement *stmt);
    //con->terminateStatement(stmt);
    env->terminateConnection(conn);
    Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);
}
catch(SQLException& ex)
{}
//.....
return 0;
}
```

Although when i run these insert statement only they fairly run well but when i forms a SQL Script structure they seems to fail. I want to do so because i want to implement rollback. What am i missing? Could anyone suggest any alternative to implement it.

Comment: just dump the sql statement, and run it directily in a sqlplus-alike tool to check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are `;` missing after both `ROLLBACK TO sp_1`

Comment: I missed ; while rewriting it. Thats all.
Thanks for reply but problem is still persistent.

Comment: BTW, you could get rid of `rollback_check_counter` (doesn't do anything useful here) and the `WHEN PROGRAM_ERROR THEN` part, since the `WHEN OTHERS THEN` block does just the same.

Comment: Actually the sql_stmt consist of 400-450 insert statement.
I intend to execute say 400-500 INSERTS at a time, so if any error occurs then [rollback_check_counter] comes into play and it can be handled. Regarding "WHEN PROGRAM_ERROR THEN block and WHEN OTHERS THEN block", I couldn't agree more, must have been lousy programing by me.